# This philosopher deliberately taught misinformation

Tags: reference-request, learning-methods

I remember reading once about a philosopher (Kierkegaard? Schopenhauer? Aristotle?) who would deliberately supply their students with misinformation that they should learn better, seek the truth. Cursory google/SEP/wiki searches did not turn up any evidence of either Kierkegaard or Schopenhauer or Aristotle distinctly teaching by such a method. Can anyone here name someone who did?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that teaching method but my best guess would be that Kierkegaard *mentions* it with respect to classical Hellenistic philosophy -- particularly to skepticism.

Comment: Sounds very zen.

Comment: I think that [Kierkegaard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard) was not a professor.

Comment: Considering all concepts are illusions, and all zen koans are grounded in concepts, it can be Nagajuna or any number of eastern philosophers.  To merely speak a truth requires a simultaneous lie.  Western philosophers, of this nature, would have to be Pyhron, sextus, etc.  This method is unavoidable in zen or pyrhonist philosophy...although I dont think this answers your question of "one" philosopher.